# How to code an "create new employees" button

Tags: button, xhtml

I'm building a web application as an apprentice developer, and I'm stuck completely on how to have this "add information" button? Would it need to be in a `<table>`?

Comment: Your question is too broad and vague? Specify what you are asking? What language you are using, what you have tried, etc...

Comment: Why do you think it may need to be in a table? If you explain, maybe we can clear up some misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm that's quite a vague question but I will try and help and give you a direction to Google things.

You might want to add a **input button** to your html for the user to click on. When the user clicks on the button you call a technology called **JQuery** which can then pass information from the client to the server via a technology called **AJAX**. AJAX can pass information from text fields of your new employees to the server.

Now in the code behind you can then call **stored procedures** and edit your database.

If you google the **bolded** text you should get a bit further with your endeavor.

Good Luck!

P.s I am from a C# ASP.net back ground.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, that question was cut of, yeah the idea is i have a list of all employees and i want to have the user have the ability to edit the list of employees and to also add new ones? im writting in html,css and im starting to learn about php, mysql and so on. I thought of having the input, im rather stuck though

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with PHP or mysql. I have found a website which explains a lot of the things you are after. I suggest reading through these tutorials http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/php-mysql/